# Probability of a "successful" arrival over time from $0$ to $t$?

Tags: self-study, random-variable, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I have this problem that I have been trying to solve using a random process (such is the task).

> There are $n$ keys. Only one of them opens the lock. The keys are tried without replacement. Find the expected number of tries before the right key is found.

I know that the probability of $k$ arrivals from time $0$ to time $t$ is given by
$$\mathbb{P}_k(t)=e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}$$ and the interrarival times follow the exponential distribution $f(t)=e^{\lambda t}$. I don't understand if this can be adapted to the keys problem above.

I've been looking into random processes with geometric distribution. However, I have not been able to find anything that would point to the expected value in question.

How do I model this problem as a random process? Is there a way to get the $f(t)$ for this process? If it's exponential, does $\lambda=1$? If it's not exponential, what is it and how do I find the parameters of the distribution?

Comment: I don't see where time is involved in the problem statement at all.  It asks for the expected *number* of tries.  The probability that it takes one try is $1/n$, two tries is $(1- 1/n)*(1/(n-1))$, and so forth... try taking it from there with a little algebra.

Comment: As jbowman said, I think you made the assumption that the process of "using the right key" is Poisson which is not an assumption you should make or need to make.

Comment: @jbowmanI understand the solution based on probabilities and I know the final answer. My task is to solve it as a queuing problem, not a probability problem. To solve is as a queuing problem, I need to know how the distribution function $f(t)$ of "interrarival times". It may be geometric distribution, but then I don't know what can be "time".

Comment: I have tried to make calculations treating "tries" as "time" (which then has uniform distribution), but the numeric results don't add up.

Comment: No, you don't - queues don't have to be continuous time!  Think of it as a birth-death process, with "death" equaling finding the right key, and the time between transitions = 1 period.

Comment: @jbowman if I have a birth-death process $X_t=i,\quad i=\overline{1,n}$ where $\mathbb{P}(X_{t+1}=X_t+1)=\frac{n-t}{n-t+1}.\mathbb{P}(X_{t+1}=X_t-1)=\frac{1}{n-t+1}$ then how do I get the expected number of steps before the first death? Writing $\sum_{t=1}^n\Big(t\cdot\frac{1}{n-t+1}\Big)$ doesn't seem to lead anywhere.

Comment: The problem is that your process doesn't stop... look at $t=n$, which contributes $n$ to the sum, although we know the expected value equals $(n-1)/2$.  On the other hand, it may be that it wasn't a helpful suggestion on my part!

Comment: @jbowman I've been looking into queues with ordered channels (not sure about the right English term). The channels are numbered and occupied in order. In this model the right key can be thought of as "loss". The probability of loss will then decrease as more channels are used. However, I don't know how to explicitly write out the formulae without the $f(t)$ mentioned below.

Comment: Do you really have to use queuing theory?  I now doubt that's a fruitful approach...

Comment: @jbowman it's not fruitful, but such is the problem. There probably is a simple way to present it as a queuing problem, but I haven't been able to pin it down. In the previous comment I meant "mentioned above", of course.